# Problems when opening xlsx with openpyxl

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl

I have a xlsx file and I tried to load this file using openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook 
wb = load_workbook('/home/file_path/file.xlsx')
```

But I get this error:

```
"wb = load_workbook(new_file)"): expected string or buffer
```

new_file is a variable with the path of the xlsx file trying to open. Does anybody knows why this happens or how I should change to read the file? Thanks!

**Update** More details about the error

```
/home/vagrant/scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py:322: UserWarning: Unknown extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg)
/home/vagrant/scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py:322: UserWarning: Conditional Formatting extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/vagrant_conf/pycharm-debug.egg/pydevd_comm.py", line 1071, in doIt
    result = pydevd_vars.evaluateExpression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
  File "/vagrant/vagrant_conf/pycharm-debug.egg/pydevd_vars.py", line 344, in evaluateExpression
    Exec(expression, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "/vagrant/vagrant_conf/pycharm-debug.egg/pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vagrant/scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 252, in load_workbook
    wb._named_ranges = list(read_named_ranges(archive.read(ARC_WORKBOOK), wb))
  File "/home/vagrant/scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/names/named_range.py", line 130, in read_named_ranges
    if external_range(node_text):
  File "/home/vagrant/scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/names/named_range.py", line 112, in external_range
    m = EXTERNAL_RE.match(range_string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: code snippet please

Comment: OK, I was wrong putting backslashes in the example, but In the code i'm using forward slashes. Are you going to vote down for every mistake/lack of info instead asking for a simple clarification?

Comment: OK, the error is not in `load_workbook`. The error occrues on `m = EXTERNAL_RE.match(range_string)`. It is in the file [named_ranges.py](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/8ce4fa462ccc9d2da7e59dd839693ff702645af2/openpyxl/workbook/names/named_range.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#named_range.py-111). Can you check all your formulas in the Excel file? I suspect, if I undestand correctly, that one formula is weird/malformed. Ideally, if you can hack the module, you can print the result of `node_text = name_node.text` at line 128 to know which one is bad.

Comment: You are right, the problem is in a corrupted formula in xlsx file

Comment: I have this same warning in Python 3.9 on macOS using pandas (not openpyxl)

Answer (score 0):

The syntaxe is:

```
wb = load_workbook(filename='file.xlsx', read_only=True)
```

The `read_only` keyword is not required.

Comment: Have you, at least, read the question? of course to read a file I need: from openpyxl import load_workbook \nwb = load_workbook('\home\file_path\file.xlsx') What i'm showing is just part of the error printed. So please be sure to understand what is being asked before answer

Comment: Could you post the entire error and give a link to the XLSX file used?

Comment: I use method into the try-except to catch the error message and the line, the error printed is `EXCEPTION IN (/server_user_folder/folder_1/folder_2/xlsx_handler.py, LINE 132 "wb = load_workbook(new_file)"): expected string or buffer`. About the link I can give you the path being used because contains business reserved information, but I can assure that path is similar to "/home/server_user_folder/folder_1/folder_2/file_name.xlsx" and that xlsx exist in that folder (i.e. I can open It with python open method)

Comment: If you pass a file like object as `wb = load_workbook(open('file.xlsx', 'rb'))`. What is the result?

Comment: I got the same error. I did an update in the question detailing the error